# PayPal REST API creating an agreement: Incoming JSON request does not map to API request

Tags: php, json, rest, curl, paypal

I'm using the PHP interface to [try to] create a billing agreement. The resulting `curl` command looks like this:

```
curl -v -X POST \
    https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements/ \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer A21...iA" \
    -d '{
         "name":"sms_from_me_test",
         "description":"SMS From Me Monthly Subscription Agreement",
         "start_date":"2017-07-17T08:33:27Z",
         "plan":"P-26R66685UX449822NJ6L2OWY",
         "payer":{"payment_method":"paypal"}}'
```

The response is always this JSON:

```
{
  "name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST",
  "message":"Incoming JSON request does not map to API request",
  "information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST",
  "debug_id":"9c2701965bf29"
}
```

Which is totally opaque to me. Okay the JSON is not accepted, it does not say why.

Just in case, compared to some example I've seen, I put square brackets around the JSON being sent.

```
    -d "[{
        ...
        }]"
```

because it looks like you're supposed to send an array of objects and not an object. That fails too.

I am able to create what looks like a valid Plan which I can activate, so I know the OAuth works like a charm. So that's not the problem.

What else can I do?!

There is the PHP code using the newest version of the PayPal PHP toolkit:

```
    $payer = new \PayPal\Api\Payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

    $agreement = new \PayPal\Api\Agreement();

    date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
    $now = time() + 60 * 5;
    $created_on = strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", $now);

    $agreement
        ->setName($plan_name)
        ->setDescription("SMS From Me Monthly Subscription Agreement")
        ->setStartDate($created_on)
        ->setPlan($plan->getId())
        ->setPayer($payer);

    try
    {
        $agreement->create($api_context);
    }
    catch(\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex)
    {
        echo "--------------------- exception\n";
        echo "Code: ", $ex->getCode(), "\n";
        echo "Data: ", $ex->getData(), "\n";
        $this->error = "Sorry. Could not create the PayPal Plan.";
        return false;
    }
```

The `Data: ...` is the same as the JSON I shown above...

My code is based on this example from PayPal's github:

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/billing/CreateBillingAgreementWithPayPal.php

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from PayPal.

The plan specification needs to be an object:

```
"plan":{"id":"P-26R66685UX449822NJ6L2OWY"}
```

The fact is that I first passed my `$plan` object to the `Agreement::setPlan()` object. But when you have a complete `$plan` object, that means you break the `Agreement` JSON.

What you cannot do:

```
$plan = \PayPal\Api\Plan::get($plan_id, $this->api_context);
$agreement->setPlan($plan);
```

Because the `get()` returns a complete plan.

What you have to do instead:

```
$reduced_plan = new \PayPal\Api\Plan();
$reduced_plan->setId($plan_id);
```

Now you have a plan object that will work in the `Agreement`:

```
$agreement->setPlan($reduced_plan);
```

The docs are definitely not clear one bit about that one.

Answer by Paypal on github: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/891